# I'm in a need for data of roads stored as a list of geolocations

Tags: list, navigation, geolocation

I need data of roads (more specific Highways in Belgium) that contain a list of geolocations (format doesn't matter).
I only need the lists of like 10 roads. Each road has a one-way direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: it is possible via OpenStreetMap or the Google Snap To Road API by manually selecting the a trace.
Also, multiple governments have data of their roads available under open license.
E.g. Flanders (one of Belgium's governments) in het Open Data Portal.